# Determination of variances from KarhunenLoeveDecomposition

Tags: image-processing, linear-algebra

I have been playing around with Karhunen-Loeve decomposition (KLD) for image analysis. It nicely provides the eigenimages, but I cannot determine how to process the matrix `m` to extract the variances for each eigenimage. I understand this well using singular value decomposition (SVD), but I cannot associate the outputs of the SVD with the `m` output of KLD. Maybe my linear algebra is a little rusty.

In pseudocode, I am looking for `Function[m] := Variance[Eigenimage]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## I. Matrices

Before discussing what is being done to images by `KarhunenLoeveDecomposition[]`, we will first need to understand its action on matrices, and its relation to the functions `SingularValueDecomposition[]` and `PrincipalComponents[]`. For the purposes of this answer, we will always perform centering for KLD:

```
SetOptions[KarhunenLoeveDecomposition, Standardized -> True];
```

Let's take some random matrix:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; m = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {4, 5}]]
   {{-1.01205, 0.826338, -1.39379, 0.41692, -0.263989},
    {1.05091, 0.421567, 1.50045, 1.47793, -0.250056},
    {-1.56187, -0.5138, 0.0222916, -0.8149, 0.548384},
    {-0.0104558, 0.754894, 0.185577, -0.400257, 1.33994}}
```

Here is its KLD. We'll assign the components to different variables for later convenience.

```
{p, q} = KarhunenLoeveDecomposition[m];

p
   {{1.13379, -0.803468, 0.617977, 0.724072, -1.67237},
    {0.142191, -0.942952, 1.14749, -0.92129, 0.574565},
    {0.787205, 0.075577, -0.481787, -0.488739, 0.107745},
    {0.0169239, -0.134779, -0.0767801, 0.102432, 0.0922034}}

q
   {{-0.342444, 0.580108, -0.506099, -0.538583},
    {-0.89816, -0.00928639, 0.397599, 0.187451},
    {-0.266189, -0.553269, -0.741631, 0.270223},
    {-0.0720045, -0.597731, 0.189111, -0.775739}}
```

The first equivalence to note can be seen if we disable centering in `KarhunenLoeveDecomposition[]` (`cm` is the explicitly centered matrix):

```
cm = Transpose[Standardize[Transpose[m], Mean, 1 &]];
nk = KarhunenLoeveDecomposition[cm, Standardized -> False];
nk - {p, q} // Chop // Flatten // Union
   {0}
```

As a reminder, we have the relationship `q.cm == p`

Now, `p` is (up to changes in sign) in fact equivalent to `Transpose[PrincipalComponents[Transpose[m]]]`. Recall that variances are computed from the columns of the principal components matrix:

```
Variance /@ p
   {1.40852, 0.85125, 0.276999, 0.0108352}
```

Now, we come to the SVD. Again, we use the centered matrix here:

```
{u, σ, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[cm];
```

Up to changes in sign, `p` and `q` are equivalent to `σ.Transpose[v]` and `Transpose[u]`, respectively.

```
σ.Transpose[v]
   {{-1.13379, 0.803468, -0.617977, -0.724072, 1.67237},
    {-0.142191, 0.942952, -1.14749, 0.92129, -0.574565},
    {0.787205, 0.075577, -0.481787, -0.488739, 0.107745},
    {-0.0169239, 0.134779, 0.0767801, -0.102432, -0.0922034}}    

Transpose[u]
   {{0.342444, -0.580108, 0.506099, 0.538583},
    {0.89816, 0.00928639, -0.397599, -0.187451},
    {-0.266189, -0.553269, -0.741631, 0.270223},
    {0.0720045, 0.597731, -0.189111, 0.775739}}
```

In particular, the SVD allows us to get the variances from the singular values:

```
Diagonal[σ]^2/(Last[Dimensions[m]] - 1)
   {1.40852, 0.85125, 0.276999, 0.0108352}
```

---

## II. Images

When `KarhunenLoeveDecomposition[]` is given a list of images, the matrix whose KLD is being actually taken is formed by joining together all the rows of the images, and then stacking these rows into one matrix. In code, if say `imgList = {img1, img2, img3}` is your list of images, then `{p, q} = KarhunenLoeveDecomposition[imgList]` is equivalent to `KarhunenLoeveDecomposition[Composition[Flatten, ImageData] /@ imgList]`. Thus, considering the discussion above, you won't be able to obtain the variance from the last component returned by `KarhunenLoeveDecomposition[]`, as it is just an orthogonal matrix.

Thus, to get the variances of the "eigenimages", do it like this:

```
Variance[Flatten[ImageData[#]]] & /@ p
```

---

[This paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0031-3203(81)90082-0) might be of interest.

Comment: The last two sentences were what I was exactly looking for. Thanks.